# DSC skipping script block

Tags: powershell, dsc

So I have a script resource:

```
Script changeThing
{
  PsDSCRunAsCredential = $ConfigureAccount
  DependsOn = "[SPWebApplication]$WebAppName"
  GetScript = 
  {
    return @{notRun="This is never reached"}
  }
  SetScript =
  {
    Write-Verbose -message "In SetScript"
    $result = Invoke-SPDSCCommand -Credential $ConfigureAccount -Arguments $varOne, $varTwo, $URL -ScriptBlock {
      function myFunction {...}
    }
  }
  TestScript =
  {
    Write-Verbose -message "In TestScript"
    return $false
  }
```

and whenever I try to run the DSC, it seems like everything in the script resource gets skipped. When I compile everything before I build it out, the write-verbose messages dont output, not even the message from the testscript, which leads me to believe that the script resource is getting passed over completely, and I'm not sure why. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You are missing '=' in the setscript?

Comment: shoot, that was a typo here, not in my source.

Comment: Well the code above appears to be in working order. What is returned from powershell when you run this? Could you post the results. Also I see the DependsOn is set. Is that dependency getting set properly? If not then the set script would never be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the configuration, you will not see any verbose messages from this script resource. This resource will be executed only on the target node when you apply the configuration. Can you please post the verbose messages that you see when you do a Start-DscConfiguration with the Verbose switch?